# How to identify the process changing audio volume

Tags: windows, winapi, audio

Scenario: a windows laptop with several audio devices (speakers, mic, headset,...) and several applications/drivers that can change volume (media players, headset, skype, softphone, keyboard,...). At some point the volume changes without user action and I need to find who or what is the source.

So I'm looking for any API or tool that would allow me to monitor changes to volume levels (those are easy to find) AND more importantly: identify the process doing the change.